# "by majority vote" vs. "by majority votes"

Tags: nouns

It appears that the CORRECT English expression is "by majority vote", as in "decisions are taken/made by majority vote".

Since "vote" is a countable noun, why isn't there an "a" or "the" before "majority vote" or why isn't it "by majority votes" ?

Comment: The short answer is that when we say "by (noun)", meaning "by means of using (noun)", we don't use an article.  I'm not sure if there is a precise answer for *why* that is, though.

Comment: @stangdon, thanks for the input. The "why" in the question was meant to indicate "shouldn't there always be an article in front of a noun, regardless of the situations, or is this an exception to the rule". Even by your explanation, shouldn't the sentence be rephrased as "decisions are made by means of using (the) majority vote" or is "majority vote" an uncountable compound noun ?

Comment: Often, a singular noun is used when a bunch of people are all doing the same thing at the same time: "After the performance, we will all sit down for the evening meal." (not "meals") "Join us on our weekend bike ride." (not "rides")

Answer (score 1):

Although "by majority vote" is commonly heard, I have also heard "by a majority vote". Further, sometimes the word 'majority' is left out altogether, as it is simply assumed that the majority vote will be the winner. In this case you may hear:

> We will decide between the two options by a vote.

or

> We will vote to decide between the two options.

As @stangdon pointed out, it is common to drop the articlle when we say "by (noun'). Examples of this usage are:

> "decided by voting", "sold by auction", "sent by train", "delivered by post", "walking by moonlight"

However, this is not a universal rule, as there are also many times in which an article will be used between "by" and "(noun)", eg:

> "decided by the majority", "sold by an auctioneer", "sent by the quickest means", "delivered by a postman", "walking by the riverside"

We use 'vote' instead of 'votes' because we are referring to the voting process, not to the number of votes that will be cast, ie there was only a single voting process. In a national or state election, in which there are individual voting processes for each individual seat, it would not be incorrect to say that the winning party is the one that had the most majority votes in each seat, although this is often reduced to saying that they won the most seats.

Why do we not usually say "decisions are made by means of using a majority vote", simply because it is so much easier to say "Decisions are made by majority vote."

Comment: thanks for your input! Unless the grammarists can confirm both "by majority vote" and "by a majority vote" are correct, it'd be difficult to explain to non-native speakers "why" by majority vote seems more commonly used. Interestingly, I see examples in your answer that seem to contradict the "it's so much easier to say by majority vote" - "we'll decide by a vote", not "by vote"; "decided by the majority", not "by majority" :)

Comment: English is a wonderfully complex language in so many ways. Full of contradictions and exceptions. There are so many instances in which native speakers say things in a particular way but there is no rule that we can point to that explains why we do so.